# jar -uf is deleting the file inside the jar

Tags: jar, java, manifest.mf

I am using jar -uf to update my MANIFEST.MF file like this:

a. jar xf jarfile.jar META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

b. edit the file

c. jar uf jarfile.jar META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

But the 'uf' command is removing MANIFEST.MF from within my jar.
What is the right way to change a file inside a jar (windows 7, jdk 1.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use winrar (or any equivalent) to open the jar, and drag/drop the files. worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For updating the manifest file the jar command provides different option -

```
jar umf manifest jar-file
The m option indicates that you want to update the JAR file's manifest.
manifest is the manifest whose contents you want to merge into the manifest of the existing JAR file.
```

examples @ http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/update.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a special option (m) for the manifest file: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Could you try with

```
jar um jarfile.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```